# Why php functions or classes cannot work like jquery plugins?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, oop, php-5.3

Why php functions or classes cannot work like jquery/ javascript plugins?

For instance,

a jquery plugin,

```
(function($){

    // Attach this new method to jQuery
    $.fn.extend({ 

        // This is where you write your plugin's name
        popup: function(options) {

            // Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                widthPopup:         500,
                absoluteLeft:       '500px'
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $cm = this.click(function(e){

                ...

                return false;

            });

        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

and then here is how you can use the plugin,

```
$('.click-me').popup();
```

or

```
$('.click-me').popup({widthPopup:300,absoluteLeft:'50%' });
```

or

```
$('.click-me').popup({absoluteLeft:'50%' });
```

as for a php function,

```
function test($parameter_1 = 100, $parameter_2 = false) {
 ....
}
```

and you have to call the function like this,

```
echo test();
```

or

```
echo test($parameter_1 = 50, $parameter_2 = true);
```

or

```
echo test(10, true);
```

and it won't work if you call the function like this,

```
echo test($parameter_2 = true);
```

Can you see what I find that php is arbitrary and a bit 'falling behind'??

Or maybe there is some advanced level of php I haven't learned yet??

Comment: falling behind? They're not the same language. Can't compare them like that. The natural suggestion would be to learn the language and use it as needed, not expect it to be the same as another

Comment: Why can't oranges be like apples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing are two different things. In the JavaScript example, you're passing associative array (hash, map, JSON, whatever ...), but in PHP, you're using named parameters.

So the matching code in PHP would be

```
function test($parameters) { ... }
```

and calling it via

```
test(array('parameter_1' => 50, 'paramater2' => true));
```

it's not as beautiful as the JavaScript version, but it does the same thing. Basically the only difference here is, that in JavaScript, you don't have to use the `array()` function to create an associative array, you can just type

```
{ javascript: "is", cool: true }
```

and it will work. The PHP alternative here is

```
array("javascript" => "is", "cool" => true)
```

Comment: Cool!  You used the words "javascript" and "beautiful" in the same sentence!

Comment: @LarryLustig Considering the languages that people use (Java, C++, PHP and even Python), JavaScript is very beautiful :) but only in the hands of a person who knows how to make it beautiful.

Comment: 'JavaScript is very beautiful' that's what I thought and that's why I raised the question about php - I know they are different. php can be very ugly coded depends on the coder.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing a hash as an argument with normal arguments. You can still do this in PHP:

```
echo test(array('parameter_2' => true));
echo test(array('parameter_1' => false, 'parameter_2' => true));
```

But I doubt that you find this pretty.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts. yea I don't find it pretty. just can't think of any way to make php 'pretty'!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason is jQuery is javascript which is a prototype language. PHP simply is not a prototype language.

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe there is some *advanced* level of php I haven't learned yet??

Yea, there is some *basic* level of php you haven't learned yet